# <select><option> and action associated with them

Tags: php, javascript, html, postgresql

I am writing a reservation system. On the main page I would give a choice of category, viewed the equipment available for booking. 
For example I have code like this:

```
<select>
        <option value = "a">A</option>
        <option value = "b">B</option>
        <option value = "c">C</option>
        <option value = "d">D</option>
        <option value = "e">E</option>
</select>
```

I wish that each choice was associated with a separate query to the database, and that was the result of a query dynamically displayed on the screen.

It would be great if you could show me some sample code.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM choices");
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
  echo '<option value="'.$row['value'].'">'.$row['value'].'</option>';
}
```

If you need separate query for each choice the code doesns't change much:

```
$query = mysql_query("(SELECT * FROM choices) UNION (SELECT * FROM choices1) [etc]");
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
  echo '<option value="'.$row['value'].'">'.$row['value'].'</option>';
}
```

Comment: I don't believe this is what has been asked. If I'm reading it correctly, Mateusz is looking to run a separate query for each choice, not a query to get the choices.

Comment: it's impossible to tell exactly what he wants. imo. Anyway I just showed an example

Comment: Brendan Bullen you're right. I am looking to run separate query for each choice.

Comment: @mate: i have added details for that

Comment: My choices are the categories and would like to click on a category to show products in that category.

Comment: @mate: what you are asking is incomprehensible for us human. Expand your first question with a lot more details and pseudcode

Comment: @yes123 Mateusz has confirmed what is required and, while I can see where the confusion is, I think it can be considered comprehensible...

Comment: @Mateusz: if my answer helped you please consider to +1 it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are two parts to your question; 1 - Detecting which query to run and 2 - Displaying the results dynamically.

**Part 1: Detecting which query to run:**

Given hard-coded choices and no parameters for the query, using your above code, you can determine which query to run using the following:

For the HTML part, as part of a form, create the select as you did above (but with a name)

```
<select name="querySelect">
    <option value="a">A</option>
    <option value="b">B</option>
</select>
```

And in the PHP:

```
$querySelect = $_GET['querySelect'];
switch($querySelect)
{
    case 'a':
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM TableA";
        break;
    case 'b':
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM TableB";
        break;
}

$results = mysql_query($sql);
```

**Part 2: Displaying the results dynamically**

With the `$results`, what you do with the data very much depends on what you want to achieve. At a very basic level, you can do the following to dynamically display a table of the results:

```
if(mysql_num_rows($results) > 0)
{
    $header = false;
    print "<table>"

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results))
    {
        if(!$header)
        {
            $headings = array_keys($row);
            print "<tr>";
            for($i=0;$i<count($headings);$i++)
            {
                print "<th>".htmlspecialchars($headings[$i])."</th>";
            }
            print "</tr>";

            $header = true;
        }

        print "<tr>";

        foreach($row as $value)
        {
            print "<td>".htmlspecialchars($value)."</td>";
        }

        print "</tr>";
    }

    print "</table>"
}
else print "<h1>No Results Found!</h1>";

mysql_free_result($results);
```

There is still alot not covered in my answer because I can't say what level of detail is required. You will also need to cover things like your connection to MySQL, error handling, formatting of the table...

**Update**
Hmmm, very interested to know why this has been downvoted. If someone can please explain in comments where I have misinterpreted the question or misguided the user, I would appreciate it.

Comment: I have a problem with this: $querySelect = $_GET['querySelect']; It returns an error UNDEFINED INDEX: QUERYSELECT

Comment: @Mateusz The querySelect index for the GET values assumes that you have given your select a name of querySelect. Is that the case?

Answer (score 0):

If you use jQuery the code might look like

```
<select id="select_id">
    <option value = "a">A</option>
    <option value = "b">B</option>
    <option value = "c">C</option>
    <option value = "d">D</option>
    <option value = "e">E</option>
</select>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#select_id').change(function(e) {
        // this code send selected value to the server
        $.post('url', {selected_value: this.value}, function(response) {
            // handle the server's response
        });
    });
</script>
```

On server side take the value from $_POST and make a query. And remember - do not trust to data from client-side. You never know who is over there. Always check incoming data and DO NOT use such constructions

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE name = '{$_POST['selected_value']}'";
```

because there might be any string including those can drop all databases, clear data and so forth.